# rviz visualization problem

Tags: rviz, moveit, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

My problem is that rviz will repeat visualizing the planed trajectory and won't stop even the arm is already at the position it should be. I am not sure whether this will cause any problems in the future at least right now I haven't met any problems for it. But I wonder whether there is a way to fix and what is the reason for this phenomenon. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288075/rviz-visualization-problem/) by [Oh233](https://answers.ros.org/users/30294/oh233/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2018-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Click the arrow to expand the "MotionPlanning" visualization in the Displays Tab, open the "Planned Path" section, and use the "Loop Animation" checkbox to toggle this behavior. See image below:

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2018-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1